# Change spinner data, android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have 2 spinners in my activity as category and sub-category.
When i choose some value from category spinner 
I want to display its related values/data in sub-category spinner.
How can i perform this?

```
   public class SellActivity extends Activity {
 private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
 private String selectedOption;
 List<String> addItemList = new ArrayList<String>();
 String[] elCat = new String[] {"Mobile", "Television", "Computers","Home Appliances","Games","Others"}; 
 String[] veCat = new String[] {"Cars", "Buses", "Motorcycles","Others"}; 
 String[] reCat = new String[] {"Apartment", "Plot", "Office","Paying Guest","Others"}; 
 String[] hCat = new String[] {"Books", "Furniture", "Musical Instrument","Watches","Others"}; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categorySellSpinner);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subCategorySpinner);
    selectedOption=String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
    System.out.println(selectedOption);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(selectedOption.equals("Electronics"))
            {
                Collections.addAll(addItemList, elCat); 
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SellActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItemList);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            else if(selectedOption.equals("Home - Lifestyle"))
            {
                Collections.addAll(addItemList, hCat); 
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SellActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItemList);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            else if(selectedOption.equals("Vehicles"))
            {
                Collections.addAll(addItemList, veCat); 
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SellActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItemList);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            else if(selectedOption.equals("Real Estate"))
            {
                Collections.addAll(addItemList, reCat); 
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SellActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItemList);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

Here is the whole code.
Data is not changing....plus old data adds onto it

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the values do not change....should i post the whole activity code??

Comment: Tried `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of each case?

Comment: added bt still not working

Comment: i have updated the code please check

Comment: i was making a silly mistake solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this in every if condition :-

```
Collections.addAll(addItemList, elCat);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItemList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Old data is getting added because you are not clearing the collection you are passing into the adapter just clear the contents of the collection before adding new data into it.

Try this :-

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        addItemList.clear();
        spinner2.setAdapter(null);


        if(selectedOption.equals("Electronics"))
        {
            Collections.addAll(addItemList, elCat);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many problems:

-- Data for `spinner1` is missing. From your code, it should be: `{"Electronics", "Home - Lifestyle", "Vehicles","Real Estate"}`

-- `spinner1` does not have an adapter set on it

-- creation and usage of list `addItemList` is not required

-- usage of `selectedOption` for checking against the selected item is not required. `onItemClick()` gives you the selected item in `int arg2`

-- calling notifyDataSetChanged() to an adapter not set to any View does nothing.

-- arrays can be passed to ArrayAdapters directly, without the need for dumping them into an ArrayList

Comment: thnx a lot buddy for your suggestion....i made so many mistakes...now i have less of the code..

Answer (score 0):

Try re-initializing the addItemList after coming inside onItemSelected before your if statement..